# Database Confusion in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to Node.js and express. Now I am planning to use database for my application. I am used to with `mysql`. when I google about using database with node.js I found something weird like any-db node-sql or some kind of weird adapters that I need to use to access my normal mysql database. So which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql I guess this is the most commonly used module for MySQL.

Comment: How long can comments be?